# finding a child object in list declared as the parent object

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm working on a screen manager class for an XNA project. I am keeping track of a list of type `GameScreen` to keep track of each of my game states. Each of my screens inherits from `GameScreen`

How would I go about finding a particular child in my list?

For example, lets say we have:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>(){Apple, Orange, Banana, Pineapple};
```

I want to write a function that takes in a certain type of fruit and returns that particular fruit from the list. How would I go about doing that?

**EDIT**

```
public Fruit findFruit(object myFruit)
{
    //use myFruit to find the correct fruit in the list
}
```

Comment: not related to your question, but i want to learn xna game dev where should i start? sorry for question

Comment: @Sam1 Here is a good start: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/gamedevelopment

Comment: sorry one more question..do you have to pay?

Comment: @Sam1 No payment is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homework?

You can do it like this:

```
public Fruit GetFruit(Type type)
{    
    return fruits.Find(x => x.GetType() == type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop throught each element and compare the type of the class that you want

foreach(Fruit f in fruits)
 {
   if(typeof(f) is typeof(Apple)
      return f;
 }